# Progress dialog spinner, spinning seamlessly

Tags: android, android-spinner

The progress dialog spinner is spinning seamlessly. I want it to be like this - the user clicks the "Check For Root" button, the spinner would spin for 5 seconds with a message "Please wait", and then the dialog box with results get displayed.
Please help!

```
package com.maverick.checkforroot;

import com.stericson.RootTools.RootTools;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = null;
private Button Root;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView Manufacturer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Manufacturer);
    String Manu = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;;
    Manufacturer.setText(Manu);

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    String Model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
    tv1.setText(Model);

    TextView Product = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Product);
    String Pro = android.os.Build.PRODUCT;;
    Product.setText(Pro);
    final Runnable mTimerExecutor = null;

    Button Root = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Root);
    Root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please wait...", true);
            mTimerHandler.postDelayed(mTimerExecutor, 5000);

        }
    });
};

        public void run() {

            if (mProgressDialog != null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    builder.setTitle("Congratulations!");
                    builder.setMessage("You Have Root Access!");

                    builder.setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }

            else  {
                 AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    builder1.setTitle("Oops!");
                    builder1.setMessage("No Root Access!");
                    builder1.setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder1.create();
                    dialog.show();  


    };

    Button BusyBox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BusyBox);
    BusyBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (RootTools.isBusyboxAvailable()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"BusyBox Is Available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No BusyBox!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. I am not sure what wrong with that.! I would like to suggest the following. It is worth a shot.

```
    private static final int SHOW_PROGRESS = 0x1;
    private static final int STOP_PROGRESS = 0x2;

  Root.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SHOW_PROGRESS);
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(STOP_PROGRESS, 5000);
        }
    });

// Handler
private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (msg.what) {
        case SHOW_PROGRESS:
             // Show your progress Bar here.
            mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
            break;

        case STOP_PROGRESS:
            progressDialog.dismiss();
              if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new         AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setTitle("Congratulations!");
                builder.setMessage("You Have Root Access!");

                builder.setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }

        else  {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder1.setTitle("Oops!");
                builder1.setMessage("No Root Access!");
                builder1.setPositiveButton("OKAY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder1.create();
                dialog.show();  
            mHandler.removeMessages(STOP_PROGRESS);
            break;
        }
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```